# Android WebView canGoBack() returns false when URL is similar

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview

I have an Android webview that I want it to go back with the Android back button. I have it working if the previous site is, for example `https://www.aaa.com/index.php` and `https://www.aaa.com/index2.php`, but canGoBack() returns false when the URLs are for example, `https://www.aaa.com/index.php?page=page1` and `https://www.aaa.com/index.php?page=page2`. I think this is probably because the URLs are the same, it's just the variables at the end that change. This is my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if (view.canGoBack()) {
                    view.goBack();
                } else {
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
        }

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

How can I make it to go back even if the variable on the URL changes?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably being hit by the bug in Chrome version 63. See: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=794020